Need to continue retrying Gmail password without being presented with account recovery
I have a Chromebook. I started to use it again recently and because my Gmail password had changed since the last use, I had to enter the old one and use the new one. But…because of Google's stupid decision to prevent password reuse, I can't remember what my password is and I need it to recover my Chromebook's data.
What I'm doing is trying to login into my Gmail account afresh. If it logs me in, then I'll know the password to use for Chromebook. The annoying thing is is that if I fail to enter the password twice, it takes me to a screen prompting me to use an alternative login method. This is slowing me doemwn. How can I make things such that Gmail always brings me back to password entry instead of asking me to use an alternative method?

I am reviewing deleted closed questions.  I was the one who closed this so I'm adding it to the reopen-review queue to allow the community a chance to do its review to decide if it should remain closed or be reopened. NB: I also am responsible for the upvote to stop it from being auto-deleted while the community reviews.
